# Installing Old Package from Old Ubuntu to New version of Ubuntu

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, 19.04, javafx

I want to install openjfx8 (which is compatible with Java 8) on Ubuntu 19.04. This was available on Ubuntu 18.04, and I had installed as follows: (Refer: [How do I get Java FX running with OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166267/how-do-i-get-java-fx-running-with-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts))

```
sudo apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 openjfx-source=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
```

But in Ubuntu 19.04 these package are not available:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy openjfx
openjfx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 11.0.2+1-1
  Version table:
     11.0.2+1-1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
```

How can I install the old package from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04?

Comment: Yes they are https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/openjfx

Comment: @Rinzwind These are openjfx (11.0.2+1-1) but I am looking for openjfx (8) compatible with Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following example illustrates how to install a package not available in a particular version of Ubuntu but available in an older Ubuntu:

- If you want to install openjfx8 in 19.04 which is available in 18.04 at `https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/arm64/openjfx/download`.

  1. Append `deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
  2. Do `sudo apt update`
  3. Install the packages: `sudo apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2`
  4. Mark hold to prevent upgrade: `apt-mark hold openjfx libopenjfx-jni libopenjfx-java`
  5. To prevent any other complications Remove `deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe` from `/etc/apt/sources.list`
  6. Do `sudo apt update`