# What happened to the Bionic Beaver openjfx 8 libraries?

Tags: apt, updates, java, javafx

I'm trying to install JavaFX for Java 8 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

I saw the answer at [Installing Old Package from Old Ubuntu to New version of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163534/installing-old-package-from-old-ubuntu-to-new-version-of-ubuntu?newreg=b1e1296f09f14c3bbc2d39c7c7a49183) modified my sources list and issued the commands, but it appears things have changed since the answer was posted.  Does anyone know where the java 8 jfx libraries can be found today?  I get errors saying those packages are not available.  Specifically:

```
Package libopenjfx-java is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package openjfx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libopenjfx-jni is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '8u161-b12-1ubuntu2' for 'openjfx' was not found
E: Version '8u161-b12-1ubuntu2' for 'libopenjfx-jni' was not found
E: Version '8u161-b12-1ubuntu2' for 'libopenjfx-java' was not found
```

Comment: I see `libopenjfx-jni | 11.0.11+0-1        | jammy/universe           | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x` available, do you have `universe` *enabled*?

Comment: Please be precise with details; 22+ means what exactly?  22.10, 23.04, 23.10 & 24.04 are from a different two year development cycle to 22.04 (20.10, 21.04, 21.10 & 22.04 being the same cycle; as cycles are two year and complete with the LTS release).  A new two year development cycle starts just after a LTS release.

Comment: While I didn't say it in the title, in my text I did specify my specific version, 22.04.3 LTS.  Also, I'm specifically trying to get the Java 8 Java FX libraries that were available in Bionic Beaver, so telling me that you see it in jammy/universe doesn't really help.

Comment: *jammy* is the *codename* of  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Ubuntu 18.04 was *bionic*....  (*repositories are stored using codenames, just as you'll find in the sources.list file*)   I copy/pasted from a CLI enquiry on my *mantic* machine... You can peruse the same detail via https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=+libopenjfx-jni&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  (though no EOSS/ESM releases there)

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I want the JavaFX libraries from Bionic Beaver, but when I add bionic main universe to my sources and issue the sudo apt install from the answer I linked, I get the error message that I specified in my question, so it looks to me like the library has moved, or been removed from the bionic archive.

Comment: When I tried your link to packages.ubuntu.com, I get a 500 HTTP error.

Comment: *bionic* is not an EOL release thus won't be found in https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ , its currently ESM or Pro only being only EOSS  (*if you understand my 'hint' but it's off-topic on this site*)  I do see `libopenjfx-jni | 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2 | bionic-security/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`  (*but I don't have ESM/Pro enabled thus won't see later packages*)